# Reference to DOM Element

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

```
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.getDropdownDimensions();
}
getDropdownDimensions() {
    this.dropdownHeight = this.ngSelectOuter?.nativeElement?.clientHeight;
    this.dropdownWidth = this.ngSelectOuter?.nativeElement?.clientWidth;
}
```

The problem I'm facing is that, I'm conditionally showing and hiding a dropdown based on the selection of a checkbox, so when I open that page and if the checkbox was checked the dropdown is shown as everything is good, but once I uncheck the checkbox and then check it, I can see the dropdown but I cannot get its Width. I get an error that the clientWidth is undefined.

Answer (score 1):

#### With Component Property

Do `ngSelectOuter` is `public`.

```js
public ngSelectOuter: Elementref<unknown>
```

Then set the width and height in the template file (You can set a default value if there is no value):

```html
<select 
   [style.width.px]="ngSelectOuter?.nativeElement?.clientWidth || 100"
   [style.height.px]="ngSelectOuter?.nativeElement?.clientHeight || 100">
</select>
```

#### With Getters

Or you can write a `get` function and write it more readable way:

```js
public get selectOuterWidth() {
   return ngSelectOuter?.nativeElement?.clientWidth || 100;
}

public get selectOuterHeight() {
   return ngSelectOuter?.nativeElement?.clientHeight || 100;
}
```

```html
<select 
   [style.width.px]="selectOuterWidth"
   [style.height.px]="selectOuterHeight">
</select>
```